# How to find Unused Security Groups of all AWS Security Groups?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, boto

How to find all the used security groups attached with all the aws resources using Boto?
Currently the following script which is giving only ec2 instances-

```
     sec_grps = ec2_conn.get_all_security_groups()  
     for group in sec_grps:   
         print group, " Instances attached ", group.instances()
```

Is there any way to get all security groups which are unused by all aws resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a slightly difficult request because Security Groups are used by many different resources, including:

- Amazon EC2 instances
- Amazon RDS instances
- VPC Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs)
- Amazon Redshift clusters
- Amazon ElastiCache clusters
- Amazon Elastic MapReduce clusters
- Amazon Workspaces
- ...and most probably other services, too

To obtain a list of unused Security Groups, you would need to query all the above services to discover which ones are "in use".

Alternatively, you could just try to delete them -- an error is generated if you try to delete a Security Group that is in-use. (But please test this method before deleting important Security Groups!)

Answer (score 0):

Manual Process: copy the security group id

> > go to network interface in ec2 console and paste SG Here in n/w interface see whether attached any ENI